# SQL label in a select list

Tags: sql, subquery

I have the table with the rows below, showing Patients(as PatientCon), Disease, and a label (0|1 as serviceInterupt).

A patient may have multiple rows in the result, IF it has both 0 label and 1 label.

```
ServiceInterrupt   Disease  PatientCon
0                   d1      1111
0                   d1      1112
1                   d1      1112
0                   d1      1113
0                   d1      1114
1                   d1      1114
1                   d1      1115
```

What i want, is to add a new column with a label (Active|Not Active as NewLabel),
showing if a patient has AT LEAST one row with serviceInterrupt = 1.

```
ServiceInterrupt   Disease  PatientCon  NewLabel
0                   d1      1111        Active
0                   d1      1112        Not Active
1                   d1      1112        Not Active     
0                   d1      1113        Active
0                   d1      1114        Not Active
1                   d1      1114        Not Active
1                   d1      1115        Not Active
```

How can i do that in SQL?

EDIT:
the table i am using is

```
patientConcerned int NOT NULL,
disease ntext NULL,
ServiceInterrupt bit NULL,
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Would you like to add the column to the table or are you trying to come up with a query that will show you the "New label" column?

Answer (score 0):

Using standard SQL, you can do this using a `case` statement and a window function:

```
select ServiceInterrupt, Disease, PatientCon,
       (case when max(ServiceInterrupt) over (partition by PatientCon) > 0
             then 'Not Active'
             else 'Active'
        end) as newLabel
from table;
```

Comment: Sorry! We post at the same time! :D

Comment: @Galma88 . . . Wow!  We seem to have answered at the same time down to the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ServiceInterrupt,
       Disease,
       PatientCon  
       (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM your_table AS B
                          WHERE A.PatientCon = B.PatientCon AND B.ServiceInterrupt = 'True')
         THEN 'Not Active'
         ELSE 'Active'
    END) AS NewLabel
FROM your_table AS A
```

Comment: Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator. This is what i get as result.

Answer (score 0):

If the previous answers aren't working for you, try something like:

```
select serviceInterrupt, disease, PatientCon, 
       (case when exists (select * 
                        from table b 
                        where a.patientCon = b.patientCon 
                          and b.serviceInterrupt = 1)
             then 'Active'
             else 'Not Active'
        end ) as newLabel
from table a;
```

The exact syntax might be different depending on what SQL engine you are using, so if you tag that it could help.

Comment: It's the same I wrote down here

Comment: I must have been writing this while you were editing - didn't spot your edit before I posted.